# SQL Query: concatenate many columns of string type in one

Tags: sql

assume my table contains following columns

```
 Roll_number numeric           not null
 Subject1    varchar(40)       null
 Subject2    varchar(40)       null
 . . .
 Subject8    varchar(40)       null
```

i have to search a subject in all these subject1 to 8 using SQL Query. what would be the best query to search a substring in all these columns keeping in mind that any one of these can have NULL value.

i wrote

```
select * 
from students_data 
where subject1="BIOLOGY" or subject2="BIOLOGY" . . . . or subject8="BIOLOGY"
```

but i need a simple query because in actual i have more than 20 columns in my table

The query

```
select * from table1 where "BIOLOGY" in (subject1,subject2,subject3)
```

was helpful but what if i have to match just the substring (part of that subject) like
    **"BIO"** in that table fields

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused; do you have one column named **roll_number** or multiple columns named like **subject1** and **subject2**?

Comment: Oh, never mind; it's still early for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM students_data
WHERE subject1 + ' ' + subject2 + ' ' + ..... + subject8 LIKE '%BIOLOGY%';
```

---

### Update 1

For **NULL** values, use below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM students_data
WHERE ISNULL(subject1,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(subject2,'')
+ ' ' + ..... + ISNULL(subject8,'') LIKE '%BIOLOGY%';
```

For using BIO, you can use `LIKE '%BIO%';`

Comment: it can't work as any of the subject field may contain NULL values. is there any alternative to it ?

Comment: no it didn't work for my problem because of NULL value in some of these fields

Comment: @adeeliqbal : Updated answer. Please let me know if you still face any problem

Comment: it makes the query a bit more complex. i was looking for some easy way. if possible.

Comment: @adeeliqbal : Just to confirm you are using MS SQL Server... right?

Comment: @adeeliqbal : If your database would have been MySQL, CONCAT_WS would have made it easier.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `IN` predicate like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students_data 
WHERE 'BIOLOGY' IN (subject1, subject2, . . . , subject8);
```

Comment: @mahmoud Gamal . it is very useful. thanks. but in actual i dont have to match the whole field. i have to actually match substring say "BIO" in the above example you have given. but the fields subject1, subject2 . .. subject8 may contain "BIOLOGY"

Answer (score 1):

This may not be faster, but I believe it is clearer.

First create a normalized view (you could just store your data this way -- which would be ideal)

```
Create View SubjectData AS
(
   SELECT Roll_number, 1 AS SubjectNumber, Subject1 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Roll_number, 2 AS SubjectNumber, Subject2 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Roll_number, 3 AS SubjectNumber, Subject3 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Roll_number, 4 AS SubjectNumber, Subject4 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Roll_number, 5 AS SubjectNumber, Subject5 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Roll_number, 6 AS SubjectNumber, Subject6 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Roll_number, 7 AS SubjectNumber, Subject7 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Roll_number, 8 AS SubjectNumber, Subject8 AS Subject FROM TABLE1
)
```

Now the select is simple:

```
SELECT Roll_number, SubjectNumber from SubjectData where CONTAINS(Subject,'Bio')
```

**N.B.** Note the use of [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx), which should be faster however you do it.

I did not test the above queries, they may have typos.

Answer (score 0):

In such case hw about this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM students_data
WHERE 
nvl(subject1,'') + ' ' + nvl(subject2,'') + ' ' + ..... + nvl(subject8,'') 
LIKE '%BIO%';
```

If your db doesnt support then go for `ifnull()` or `decode()`